# Completeness of subsets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S,T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be given by 
 $S= \{ x \in \mathbb {R} : 2 x^2 \cos\frac1x =1\}$  and
 $T= \{ x \in \mathbb {R} : 2 x^2 \cos\frac1x \leq1\} \cup \{0\}$ . Then ,under the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ , which one is complete?

My guess is both should be complete. As both sets are closed any cauchy sequence converges inside. But the answer given is only S. Am I making mistake?

Comment: Have you attempted to prove either of your guesses?

Comment: I was thinking since in R under usual metric any cauchy seq,should converge and a subset S of R may not be complete,because of the fact that cauchy seq may converge outside. But for S,T this will not happen as they are closed.

Comment: You're right! Both are complete.

Comment: To show that $S$ and $T$ are complete, as subsets of a complete space, you only need to show that they are closed. And both are! Note that in definition of $T$, if $\{0\}$ was not included, then $T$ would not be closed

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Not necessary.If $f(0)$ doesn't exist then $y\in \{x\in \Bbb R: f(x)=1\}$ $ \iff $ $(0\ne y\in \Bbb R\land f(y)=1)$ $ \iff$ $ y\in \{x\in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}: f(x)=1\}.$

Comment: +1 for finding an error in a textbook or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, closed subsets of complete metric spaces are complete, therefore it suffices to show that subsets are closed. Since continuous preimages of closed sets are closed, we know that $$S = f^{-1}(\{1\}), \ f(x) := 2x^2 \cos(1/x)$$ is complete. Can you apply a similar argument to $T$?

Comment: Complement of { x| f(x)<=1} is {x| f(x)>1} which is preimage of (1,infinity) and continuous fn pulls back open sets to open sets. I was thinking the proof by sign preserving property of continuous fn but this one is nicer!thanks.

Comment: @ANJANSAMANTA Even simpler: the first set whose union is $T$ is the preimage of $(-\infty, 1]$, which is closed.